# What are the alternatives for sleep to delay functions? how to run asyncio.Timer()?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio

The following is a double question but it's significant to know if it could.

After searching for an alternative I found some methods like asyncio.sleep(), asyncio.Timer(), Threading.Timer(), ...etc

However, after making the research in detail I found that anything working with **coroutines** is the best choice to get rid of the memory lack so, from searching I found something called asyncio.Timer() which is the best choice.

Basically, what I want to do is a game that can handle more than one million events for one million users.

For example, I need to "upgrade building" and this would be an event that will take **n** of time to upgrade it. Now I would like to make such a workflow to trigger at a specific time when the time of upgrading a building is ready, there are many ways to achieve that like job-crons I know but I need to achieve that by seconds as well not only by minutes like job-crons do as well as I need to go apart from lacking memory when I use traditional way when I use **sleep** by **time.sleep()** or by **asyncio.sleep()**.

However, when I used asyncio.Timer() I got **AttributeError** because Timer is not a method to work with.

Comment: There is no `asyncio.Timer` class or method available in Python.

Comment: actually, I used google bard to search for this I found now something else such as threading.Timer() and atimer.Timer()

Comment: Google Bard frequently makes up technical information. Don't believe it unless you can find authoritative documentation that provides the same information.

Comment: sorry for that, but I have a question if that is possible, Is there any way to create a scheduled event by using coroutines in Python asyncio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loop.call_at` to have similar behavior to `threading.Timer`, `asyncio.Timer` does not exist in Python Standard Library.

Note that `loop.call_at` gets `when` argument, the value of the argument should be based on `loop.time()`, so it is internat eventloop time.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial


def callback_one() -> None:
    print("Callback_one")


def callback_n(n: int) -> None:
    print(f"Callback {n}")


async def main():
    print("Started")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    print(loop.time())
    timer_handler_1 = loop.call_at(loop.time() + 10, callback_one)
    timer_handler_2 = loop.call_at(loop.time() + 5, partial(callback_n, n=5))
    print(timer_handler_1.when(), timer_handler_2.when())
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    print("Finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying but I would ask about asyncio.sleep() because I knew that it affects memory so, is there any alternative to it? where I found that coroutines can do that because it doesn't use OS to handle the events, instead, it uses coroutine objects which makes it much faster. so, have you any information about that?

Comment: @AbdelhamedAbdin you can use `loop.call_at` instead of `asynio.sleep`, I've provided examples in the answer.